# ssis output to file error in job - Cannot open the datafile

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a ssis job scheduled to run.
It executes a procedure and then selects from a table to output to a file.
The ssis package runs fine in ssis and manually running the dtsx file.

When it runs as a job, all of it completes fine except the part where it tries to save to a file.

Here's the error ( i removed hostname\username)

```
Executed as user: {hostnamexxx\usernamexxx}. Microsoft (R) SQL Server  
Execute Package Utility  
Version 10.0.1600.22 for 32-bit  
Copyright  (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.     
Started:  2:33:29 PM   
Error: 2014-09-30 14:36:23.57      
    Code: 0xC020200E     
    Source: Data Flow Task Flat File Destination [22]      
    Description:  Cannot open the datafile "P:\\Ordbsjia_ORDER_0003637.DAT".  
End Error  
Error: 2014-09-30 14:36:23.57      
    Code: 0xC004701A     
    Source: Data  Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline      
    Description: component "Flat File Destination" (22) failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020200E.  
End Error  
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).   
Started:  2:33:29 PM   
Finished: 2:36:23 PM   
Elapsed:  174.422 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step  failed.
```

Comment: `Cannot open the datafile "P:\` First two thoughts are that the sql agent account does not have the permission to create files there. Second and probably more likely is that the account does not have that drive letter mapped.

Comment: P:\ is mapped from a folder on the same host. I've even added Everybody Full Control under Security.  I checked the sql server agent in services.msc and Log On is my own userid I'm currently logged in with.

Comment: It's something to do with the share.  I changed a dtsConfig variable for it to write to a local folder and all works good.  Any idea on how to get it to write to a share?

Comment: Using a network share is the same mechanism from an SSIS perspective as a local file. If you try the UNC path, does it write `\\server\share\myfile.dat` If so, then there's an issue with the account that the SSIS is being executed under. If it is unable to write to the path using a UNC, then it's a permission issue

Comment: OK. So, I set folder paths in dtsConfig file.  Should it look like \\\\server\\share\\  ??